# LINQ: Select where object does not contain items from list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm struggling with LINQ syntax here...thought I'd toss it out here. I cant find exactly what I'm looking for anywhere else.

OK, say I've got this:

```
public class Bar
{
   public int BarId { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
   public List<Bar> BarList { get; set; }
}

List<Foo> fooBunch = GetABunchOfFoos(); //let's just assume I'm getting more than one
List<Foo> fooSelect = new List<Foo>;
List<Bar> filterBars = GetAFewBars(); //assume I'm getting like 2 or 3

fooSelect = (from f in fooBunch
             where !(from b in f.BarList select b.BarId).Contains(ITEM FROM filterBars.BarId)
             select f).ToList();
```

So, long story short I want to use LINQ to filter out my list of objects based on objects from another list. I hope this makes sense. I think I'm just lost on the Contains portion...I don't know how to write that.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

In general, you're looking for the "Except" extension.

```
var rejectStatus = GenerateRejectStatuses();
var fullList = GenerateFullList();
var rejectList = fullList.Where(i => rejectStatus.Contains(i.Status));
var filteredList = fullList.Except(rejectList);
```

In this example, GenerateRegectStatuses() should be the list of statuses you wish to reject (or in more concrete terms based on your example, a `List<int>` of IDs)

Comment: This is really close...the trick would be to create the rejectList from dynamic statuses. It would be more like where i => i.Status in(list<statuses>). Can I do something like that? Basically another LINQ statement I guess?

Comment: Absolutely, to build the rejectList, you'd just have to devise a way to get a list of rejects you don't want.

For example: `var rejectList = fullList.Where(i => rejectStatuses.Contains(i.Status));`

I'll update my original answer to reflect this change.

Comment: How would I do this in just one line? I understand it might not be possible.

Answer (score 93):

dump this into a more specific collection of just the ids you don't want

```
var notTheseBarIds = filterBars.Select(fb => fb.BarId);
```

then try this:

```
fooSelect = (from f in fooBunch
             where !notTheseBarIds.Contains(f.BarId)
             select f).ToList();
```

or this:

```
fooSelect = fooBunch.Where(f => !notTheseBarIds.Contains(f.BarId)).ToList();
```

Comment: Nice.  i like this answer better. +1

Comment: This answer is better than the selected

Comment: Clean and simple ! Nice

Comment: @Rarepuppers - I spend a few minutes trying to understand the accepted answer, then looked here to see suggested what I already typed before I knew for sure if it worked that way...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I've been looking to UNDERSTAND how it works. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 7):

Try this simple LINQ:

```
//For a file list/array
var files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

//simply use Where ! x.Contains
var notContain = files.Where(x => ! x.Contains(@"\$RECYCLE.BIN\")).ToList();

//Or use Except()
var containing = files.Where(x => x.Contains(@"\$RECYCLE.BIN\")).ToList();
    notContain = files.Except(containing).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

I have not tried this, so I am not guarantueeing anything, however

```
foreach Bar f in filterBars
{
     search(f)
}
Foo search(Bar b)
{
    fooSelect = (from f in fooBunch
                 where !(from b in f.BarList select b.BarId).Contains(b.ID)
                 select f).ToList();

    return fooSelect;
}
```

Comment: From what I can tell, b.ID doesn't compile. The Contains method seems to loose context of b.

Comment: You're using two variables named `b`, and the compiler probably finds it ambiguous.