# Lightswitch Sql Filter list based on contents of second list

Tags: c#, sql, filter, visual-studio-lightswitch, autocompletebox

[image: Image of two lists]

I have generate this screen using Lightswitch.  When a team selects a club from the home team Auto Complete Box it populates the home players list with players who play for that club.  I also have a Select button (not shown) that will add the selects home player and add it to the match players collection.  After that I want to filter the Home players list to not show the players that have been selected.

I just can't work out how to filer the list based on the entire contents of the second list...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be a simpler way to achieve what you want. Add a boolean field called Selected to the Home Players collection. When a Home Player is selected to be in the Match Players collection, set that boolean to True. Make sure the Home Players collection has a filter on Selected = False.

You might need to refresh the screen manually. And if you're saving data, you'll also need to think about what happens to the Home Players collection - possibly make sure somewhere in the save pipeline that Selected is always false when saved. But all that sounds a lot easier than filtering a collection based on another one which I'm not even sure is possible without some serious contortions.

Comment: I can see the logic there,  when i am home this afternoon i will give this idea a nudge and see if this can work.  I shouldn't see how this or some permeation of this shouldn't work...Will post when sorted.  Thanks

Comment: The contortions might not be too serious if you do want to do it your originally conceived way. Set a parameter on the Home Players query which is a delimited string of Match Player ids. This will initially be empty and you will update the string in code whenever a Home Player is selected. In the pre process code for the Home Players query, turn that delimited string into a proper List and then use the Except extension in your Linq query. Example here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640259/linq-select-where-object-does-not-contain-items-from-list) .

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this.  I think i like to first option as it looks to be a lot cleaner.  I have played round with it a little bit, but seem to be getting validation errors when trying to save.  I will work on it a bit more to sort out the validation errors and hopefully find a clean working solution...