# Get objects whose property does not exist in enumerable

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Multiple answers have led me to the following 2 solutions, but both of them do not seem to be working correctly.

What I have are 2 objects

```
public class DatabaseAssignment : AuditableEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string User_Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Database_Id { get; set; }       
}

public class Database : AuditableEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Server { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public Guid DatabaseClientId { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the front-end will return all selected Database objects (as IEnumerable) for a given user. I am grabbing all current DatabaseAssignments from the database for the given user and comparing them to the databases by the Database.ID property. My goal is to find the DatabaseAssignments that I can remove from the database. However, my solutions keep returning all DatabaseAssignments to be removed.

```
if (databases != null)
{
    var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(_context);
    var userDatabaseAssignments = unitOfWork.DatabaseAssignments.GetAll().Where(d => d.User_Id == user.Id);

    //var assignmentsToRemove = userDatabaseAssignments.Where(ud => databases.Any(d => d.Id != ud.Database_Id));
    var assignmentsToRemove = userDatabaseAssignments.Select(ud => userDatabaseAssignments.FirstOrDefault()).Where(d1 => databases.All(d2 => d2.Id != d1.Database_Id));
    var assignmentsToAdd = databases.Select(d => new DatabaseAssignment { User_Id = user.Id, Database_Id = d.Id }).Where(ar => assignmentsToRemove.All(a => a.Database_Id != ar.Database_Id));

    if (assignmentsToRemove.Any())
    {   
       unitOfWork.DatabaseAssignments.RemoveRange(assignmentsToRemove);
    }
    if (assignmentsToAdd.Any())
    {
       unitOfWork.DatabaseAssignments.AddRange(assignmentsToAdd);
    }
    unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think u are looking for an Except extension, have a look at this link

[LINQ: Select where object does not contain items from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640259/linq-select-where-object-does-not-contain-items-from-list)

Or other way is with contains see below Fiddler link :

https://dotnetfiddle.net/lKyI2F

Comment: I followed the answer on this SO and still have the same problem.
    var databaseIds = databases.Select(d => d.Id).ToList();
    var assignmentsToRemove = userDatabaseAssignments.Where(ud => !databaseIds.Contains(ud.Database_Id));

AssignmentsToRemove still contains objects with matching Database_Id's.

Comment: What list is databaseids? Is it the collection of ids you want or the ones you don't want? Try select ids which you don't want into a list then replace above with: userDatabaseAssigbments.Where(lst => !idsDontwant.Contains(lst.Id)).ToList();    I'm not on my laptop so can't test anything.

Comment: databaseids is the list of database ids I want since I'm returning the selected items from the front end. So, I need to get the databaseassignments that do not contain the id's in that list in order to remove them.

Comment: I have updated my answer and added a fiddle link for you, please check