# How to check available hotel rooms

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am making a hotel reservation system in windows form by using SQL with LINQ. I have tables such as reservation tabel and room table. In reservation table I have checkin and checkout dates. I have no problem to show those rooms from reservation table in a specific date, but I don't know how to show rooms that are available on specific dates. I don't how to compare or filter out `RoomsId` from reservation table and room table.

Here is how I am getting rooms from reservation table on a specific date (checkin and checkout):

```
DateTime StartDateWantToBook = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
DateTime EndDateWantToBook = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString());

var ReservedRooms = (from u in db.Room join b in db.Reservation on u.RoomId equals b.RoomId join f in db.Floor on u.FloorId equals f.FloorId join ty in db.RoomType on u.RoomTypeId equals ty.RoomTypeId where StartDateWantToBook <= b.EndDate && b.StartDate <= EndDateWantToBook
 select new {
  RomId = b.RoomId,
   Floor = f.FloorName,
   RommsNr = u.RumNummer,
   Room_Type = ty.AmountRomms
   // But Here by somehow I think I have to run
   // another Linq query to filter RoomsId and show only those who do not exists in Reservation table.                             
 }
).ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ReservedRooms;
```

So the question is How to show all rooms in Rooms table that do not exist in Reservartionroom in a specific dates. Thank you again!

Comment: You may just need to check that the last process on each room was a checkout or null, I am not sure about the syntax but it should be similar to this : b.Last().ProcessType == "Checkout". this should be added to your where statement. Also I see that you only include rooms that has a reservation before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must work for you.

```
var AvailebleRooms = (from u in db.Room
                      where (!u.Reservation.Any(b => b.EndDate >= StartDateWantToBook && b.StartDate <= EndDateWantToBook))
                      select u).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select `AllRooms`, `ReservedRooms` in a specific date and filter `AllRoom` by list reservartion. That's my Idea, maybe contains is wrong.

```
DateTime StartDateWantToBook = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
DateTime EndDateWantToBook = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString());

var AllRooms = (from u in db.Room join b in db.Reservation on u.RoomId equals b.RoomId join f in db.Floor on u.FloorId equals f.FloorId join ty in db.RoomType on u.RoomTypeId equals ty.RoomTypeId select new {
 RomId = b.RoomId,
  Floor = f.FloorName,
  RommsNr = u.RumNummer,
  Room_Type = ty.AmountRomms
  // But Here by somehow I think I have to run
  // another Linq query to filter RoomsId and show only those who do not exists in Reservation table.                              
}).ToList();

var ReservedRooms = (from u in db.Room join b in db.Reservation on u.RoomId equals b.RoomId join f in db.Floor on u.FloorId equals f.FloorId join ty in db.RoomType on u.RoomTypeId equals ty.RoomTypeId where StartDateWantToBook <= b.EndDate && b.StartDate <= EndDateWantToBook select new {
 RomId = b.RoomId,
  Floor = f.FloorName,
  RommsNr = u.RumNummer,
  Room_Type = ty.AmountRomms
  // But Here by somehow I think I have to run
  // another Linq query to filter RoomsId and show only those who do not exists in Reservation table.

}).ToList();

var result = AllRoom.Except(ReservedRooms);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ReservedRooms;
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but I Think AllRooms ling goes to ReserverdRomms and ReservedRoom linq to on the contrary AllRooms, right? In both Linq you have Reserved rooms

Comment: as you mentioned it is not working with Contain becouse RoomsId is an integer

Comment: I think AllRooms include ReserverdRomms  and do not exist in Reservartionroom in a specific dates.So that I get all and select room which do not  exist in ReserverdRomms

Comment: but both are exact equals linq codes. It's only names different AllRooms and ReservedRooms. The linq code is the same, is that should to be?

Comment: AllRoom don't have where for specific dates ( it's take all Room )

Comment: thank you , I realy appricate your help. But I want to show Rooms not reserved, like rooms aveleble. And then I get error about ! where!ReservationRooms.where(...) I get following error, "Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'IEnumerable<<anonymous type: int RomId>>'" Thank you again!

Comment: I forgot Except , you can see it in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640259/linq-select-where-object-does-not-contain-items-from-list)

Comment: I got the right solution from Jonas. Check his answer. Thank you for trying helping me.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need left outer join AllRooms and ReservedRooms to get rooms only using where clause with specific dates