# C# Linq Query with foreign Key relationship

Tags: c#, linq

Please consider the following scenario,

I have a two tables `SplitRequest` and `SplitRequestApproval`.

`SplitRequest` has a collection of `SplitRequestApproval` while `SplitRequestApproval` has one of `SplitRequest`

What the above means is that there is a one to many relationship between `SplitRequest` and `SplitRequestApproval`

`SplitRequestApproval` has `ApproverUserId` `SplitRequestId` `DateApproved` etc... as column. while `SplitRequest` has the actual request details.

The question then is I want a linq query that will get `List<SplitRequest>` that a logged in user (Approver) has not attended too.

So if user `A` with ID `123` Logs in, and navigates to the `SplitRequest` View,  The view should only show request he has not attended to yet. therefore if he approves a `SplitRequest` wiht ID `12` that item should not be part of the request visible to him anymore. `SplitRequestApproval` gets a new row with `SplitRequestId` as `12` and `Userid` `123`

How can this be achieved with linq.

```cs
var request = await _context.SplitRequestApproval
   .Include(c => c.SplitRequest)
   .Where(c => c.ApproverUserId != loggedInUserId)
   .Select(c => c.SplitRequest)
   .ToListAsync();
```

this is returning 0 items. whereas there  are SplitRequest the loggedin user has not attended to

A solution I got but i considered it a long route

```
//gets the list of splitRequests
 var splitRequests = await  _context.SplitRequest.ToListAsync();

//loops through each request
            foreach (var item in splitRequests)
            {
//check if the request has been approved by the user
                var IsExistApprovalForLoggedInUser = await _context.SplitRequestApproval.AnyAsync(c => c.SplitRequestId == item.SplitRequestId && c.ApproverUserId == loggedInUserId);
                if (IsExistApprovalForLoggedInUser)
                {
//if yes remove from list
                    splitRequests.Remove(item);
                }
            }
```

I think there should be a linq query that will give me same result and faster

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640259/linq-select-where-object-does-not-contain-items-from-list

Comment: What do you mean by a SplitRequest which the logged in user has not attended to? Is this every splitRequest where.ApproverUserId != loggedInUserId ?

Comment: From eyeballing the code, it looks like your Linq code is only selecting SplitRequests that do have a SplitRequestApproval where the user is someone other than the current user. So SplitRequests that don't have a SplitRequestApproval at all won't be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Linq code is selecting SplitRequestApprovals where the user is not the current user, then navigating to the SplitRequest.

This means that SplitRequests without any SplitRequestApprovals at all won't be selected, which I think is where your problem is. Also, SplitRequests with approvals from multiple users will be selected multiple times.

What you want to do is select SplitRequests that don't have any SplitRequestApprovals by the current user. Something like this:

```
var request = await _context.SplitRequest
    .Where(c => !c.SplitRequestApprovals.Any(c => c.ApproverUserId == loggedInUserId))
    .ToListAsync()
```